# When do $C_1$ and $C_2$ exist in $C_1e^{at}=e^{at+C_2}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When does $C_1$ and $C_2$ exist in $C_1e^{at}=e^{at+C_2}$?

For my differential equations class, we are instructed to make the assumption as described above.  This is all fine and dandy, and while the book doesn't mention it, I'd like to know if we can *always* make this assumption... I can't seem to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

If $C_1=e^{C_2}$, then $C_1e^{at}=e^{C_2}e^{at}=e^{at+C_2}$.

$C_2=\ln C_1$ exists so long as $C_1>0$. On the other hand, given any real $C_2$, $C_1=e^{C_2}$ is always possible.

Comment: As a small addition to this: if $C_1, C_2$ are allowed to be complex, it always works for non-zero $C_1$.